# Maximum dimension of Commuting matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given $V\subset\mathbb{F}^{n\times n}$ and $\forall A_{1},A_{2}\in V$, we have $$A_{1}A_{2}=A_{2}A_{1}$$ Then what is the maximum dimension of $V$?

$\textbf{My attempts}$:

An example in which $\dim V=[1+n^{2}/4]$:
$$V=\text{span}\left\{I,\begin{pmatrix}O&B\\O&O\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$

Other ideas: given that every two matrices commute, we may choose a certain basis under which every matrix is upper-triangular.

Comment: [This may help](https://mathoverflow.net/q/69654/90655).

Comment: Look like you nailed it: [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/29089/41094)